# How can I find the index of the first "element" in my string using Java?

Tags: java, parsing, string, prolog

I'm working on writing a simple Prolog interpreter in Java.

How can I find the last character index of the first element either the head element or the tail element of a string in "List Syntax"?

List Syntax looks like:

> (X)
>   (p a b)
>   (func (func2 a) (func3 X Y))
>   (equal eve (mother cain))

The head for each of those strings in order are:
Head: "X", Index: 1
Head: "p", Index: 1
Head: "func", Index: 4
Head: "equal", Index: 5

Basically, I need to match the string that immediately follows the first "(" and ends either with a space or a closing ")", whichever comes first.  I need the character index of the last character of the head element.

How can I match and get this index in Java?

---

Brabster's solution is really close.  However, consider the case of:
((b X) Y)

Where the head element is (b x).  I attempted to fix it by removing "(" from the scanner delimiters but it still hiccups because of the space between "b" and "x".

Similarly:
((((b W) X) Y) Z)

Where the head is (((b w) x) Y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class (introduced in Java 1.5) might be a good place to start.

Here's an example that I think does what you want (updated to include char counting capability)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] data = new String[] {
                "(X)",
                "(p a b)",
                "(func (func2 a) (func3 X Y))",
                "(equal eve (mother cain))",
                "((b X) Y)",
                "((((b W) X) Y) Z)"
        };


        for (String line:data) {
            int headIdx = 0;
            if (line.charAt(1) == '(') {
                headIdx = countBrackets(line);
            } else {
                String head = "";
                Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
                s.useDelimiter("[)|(| ]");
                head = s.next();
                headIdx = line.indexOf(head) + head.length() - 1;
            }
            System.out.println(headIdx);
        }

    }

    private static int countBrackets(String line) {
        int bracketCount = 0;
        int charCount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char c = line.charAt(i);
            if (c == '(') {
                bracketCount++;
            } else if (c == ')') {
                bracketCount--;
            }
            if (bracketCount == 0) {
                return charCount + 1;
            }
            charCount++;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Brackets not nested properly");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
4
5
5
13
```

It's not a very elegant solution, but regexes can't count (i.e. brackets). I'd be thinking about using a parser generator if there's any more complexity in there :)

Comment: It might also be worthwhile looking at parser generators like ANTLR or JavaCC if you don't actually want to deal with the parsing yourself.

Comment: @Brabster, how yould you deal with the string: "((b X) Y)" where (b x) was the head of the list?

Comment: @Brabster, I tried removing "(" from the list of delimeters but I still run into trouble because of the space inbetween b and x.

Comment: Good question. I'll have a think, it's probably beyond the capabilities of the simple regex I have here... hmmm

Comment: I suppose you can keep on nesting, i.e. ((((b W) X) Y) Z)?

Comment: and in the case above what is the head of the list?

Comment: The head of the list above is: (((b W) X) Y)

Comment: I guess you just count brackets then. If the second character is a bracket, count the brackets in and out until you find the matching close bracket for the second one - and that's your head. Else, second character not a bracket, use the algorithm above to get the head.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't just brute force it?  Something like this?

```
public int firstIndex( String exp ) {
    int parenCount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < exp.length(); i++) {
        if (exp.charAt(i) == '(') {
            parenCount++;
        }
        else if (exp.charAt(i) == ')') {
            parenCount--;
        }
        if (parenCount == 0 && (exp.charAt(i+1) == ' ' || exp.charAt(i) == ')')) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

I may be missing something here, but I *think* that would work.

Comment: I missed the extra comment from Brabster where he mentions doing basically exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a proper parser ([operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) in the case of Prolog) and represent the terms as trees of Java objects for further processing.

Comment: I'm using this as a minimal, minimal example of one feature in prolog (unification), where I don't think a lexer/parser is warranted.

Comment: Then I would build the object structures directly and don't bother with strings.

Comment: @starblue, that is what I would probably do if I were doing this, build the object structures by hand.